# TextArea not updating in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I'm defining the TextArea in my controller class like this:

```
@FXML 
private TextArea txtAreaStatus;
```

And I'm trying to append text to the TextArea using this code:

```
@FXML
public void clickGo (ActionEvent event) {

    txtAreaStatus = new TextArea("");

    txtAreaStatus.appendText("data");

    System.out.println("clicked");
}
```

I'm really confused as to why my text area is not updating. No errors whatsoever.

When I click the button, `clicked` gets printed on the screen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `txtAreaStatus = new TextArea("");` and try again.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha this is embarrassing but when I didn't have that the TextArea did not show up on the UI at all. And now when I remove that line, it all works fine. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are using `FXML` and `Controller` combination, controls references are annotated with `@FXML` in the controller. The objects are injected into their respective references when the fxml is loaded. *Therefore you don't need to do define a new object for them.*

In your code you need to remove :

```
txtAreaStatus = new TextArea("");
```

because this makes you loose the reference to the object of `TextField` on the scene and defines a **new** `Textfield` object (which is not on the scene). You are later trying to do operations on this new object.